# No suitable HttpMessageConverter found when trying to execute restclient request

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use `Spring for Android rest client` to send data with an `http post` , to avoid creating and parsing the json data.

From their [manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e426) they have the following method:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(url, m, String.class)
```

After the method is called I get the following exception:

```
No suitable HttpMessageConverter found when trying to execute restclient request
```

My activity code snippet is :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
Message m = new Message();
m.setLibrary("1");
m.setPassword("1395");
m.setUserName("1395");
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, m, String.class);
```

And the Message object is :

```
public class Message {
    private String UserName, Password, Library;

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public String getLibrary() {
        return Library;
    }

    public void setLibrary(String library) {
        Library = library;
    }
}
```

Why can't it `convert the Message object to JSON` ?

Comment: Have you added a `HttpMessageConverter<Message>`?

Comment: restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new HttpMessageConverter<Message>()) I need to add it this way?

Answer (score 7):

There could be a few different reasons why this can happen. In my case, i had the RestTemplate already wired in, but still got this error. Turns out, i had to add a dependency on "jackson-databind":

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have not added a `Message`-specific `HttpMessageConverter`. `HttpMessageConverter` is an `interface`. You need to create a class that implements `HttpMessageConverter<Message>` and add an instance of that class to the `RestTemplate` via `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MyMessageConverter());`

Comment: Ok, I get it now, but what is the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() for? isn't that used for converting the object?

Comment: Since `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` extends `AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object>`, I would assume that `RestTemplate` will only use it for explicitly `Object` instances. Frankly however, I am not familiar with it. Try implementing your own using Jackson or Gson explicitly and see if it works, then try to figure out how to use `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`. That is my suggestion anyway.

Comment: Ok I will go with that, i'm giving you +1 for the answer, the odd thing is that from their reference manual they have a simple object and they don't have anything else without implementing another HttpMessageConverter.

Comment: Please post the solution using `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` if you figure it out. I would be interested in knowing.

Comment: well I have found something interesting(I haven't tried it yet).
it seems like you can add jsonparser
JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());

and parse the result to a class.
Look at the example shown here:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

It is the googleplaces.class
seems to do exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine in general. Maybe this is a version problem. Check whether you use Jackson 2, and if so, change the converter to `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

No need for something like `HttpMessageConverter<Message>`.

On a side node:
Java convention is to use lower casing for variable names. So, it would be more readable for other Java developers to do:

```
private String library;

public void setLibrary(String library) {
    this.library = library;
}
```